# How to automatically determine which PHP extensions are used by a project?

Tags: php

Is there a way to automatically find out which PHP extensions are used by a particular project you have the source code of?

When migrating a website from a one server to another, I often find myself wondering what PHP extensions should I enable for the website to function normally. Yes, this use case would probably be irrelevant if the project used Docker or had an exhaustive install guide, but it's not always the case.

I was thinking of a script that went through all of the .php files and looked for specific function calls or classes, for exeample:

- `new mysqli(` or `mysqli_connect(`: mysqli
- `imagecreate(` or `imagepng` or `imagejpeg` or ... : gd
- `curl_init(` : curl

Does a similar script already exist? If not, would it make sense to write it?

Comment: Sadly - no. That's why we resort to having projects as `composer` projects where you can specify extension and library dependency. If you have a project that isn't a `composer` project, then you'd have to analyse the code and try and determine which extension is required to provide that functionality.

Comment: you can write it in shell, find + grep or awk

Comment: It's not a complete solution, but check out https://github.com/glenscott/php-dependencies

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md This is interesting. So you can manually specify dependencies (including PHP extensions) via composer. But still, `composer.json` has to be populated manually so if you add code that uses an extension and forget to add it to `composer.json` (because it was already available on your system for example), you are still having to go through the code manually when migrating (weeks / months / years later).

Comment: @DarioSpagnolo wait. So you wouldn't put your composer file into version control, i.e. git?!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ yes, composer.json would be under version control, but it would still need to be manually modified everytime you use a new extension. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ https://github.com/glenscott/php-dependencies : awesome! It comes really close to what I was talking about. If you write an answer about it, I'll validate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Writing as answer as requested by OP [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041290/how-to-automatically-determine-which-php-extensions-are-used-by-a-project?noredirect=1#comment55839445_34041290)</sup>

### glenscott/php-dependencies

Although not a complete solution, this will lessen the manual work you'll have to do: https://github.com/glenscott/php-dependencies

A few caveats are;

- Your source code and its dependencies must lie under one directory -- included/required files outside this directory are not scanned
- As it stands, only *function* dependencies are found. This means that class dependencies are not checked.

You can read the blog post by the author here: http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/finding-function-dependencies-in-your-php-applications/

**To run**

You can do these via the command line or through a web browser.

- **Step 1)** Getting PHP environment details:
  `php get-env-functions.php`
- **Step 2)** Find dependencies:
  `php scan-dependencies.php`

Comment: As an alternative, I've developed a similar tool that can catch both function and class dependencies using Reflection. See https://github.com/RogerGee/php-ext-depends

Answer (score 8):

I can suggest 2 different approaches: Composer and PHP CompatInfo.

### Composer

For a Composer project with dependencies installed, you can check the requirements using the command

```sh
composer check-platform-reqs
```

Note that it does not analyse the code, it only checks information from `composer.lock` file
OR files in `vendor` directory, whichever exists.
Example of result:

```
composer-plugin-api  1.1.0                                                    success
ext-ctype            7.2.24                                                   success
ext-curl             7.2.24                                                   success
ext-dom              20031129                                                 success
ext-zip              n/a       phpoffice/phpspreadsheet requires ext-zip (*)  missing
php                  7.2.24                                                   success
```

Developers of packages should include information about required PHP extensions in `require` section of `composer.json`,
e.g. `"ext-curl": "*"`.
Obviously, the effectiveness of this method highly depends on the punctuality of developers
but this check is fast and easy to use.

### PHP CompatInfo

The latest version and development documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/llaville/php-compat-info).
The end-user documentation can be found
[here](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/manual/current/en/getting-started.html),
also you can download a PHAR file from there, but it may be outdated
(currently it hosts version 5.0.12 while GitHub and Packagist has 5.4.2).
The recommended way to install this library is through Composer.
I suggest installing it separately, not in project which you want to test because:

- PHP CompatInfo also requires some PHP extensions and you want to test your own project
  without addition of extra dependencies.
- PHP CompatInfo may require versions of packages which conflict with your project,
  e.g. version 5.4.2 requires `symfony/config: ^4.4|^5.0`, if your project already requires `symfony/config: ^3.0`
  then you unable to install the latest version of PHP CompatInfo as part of this project,
  even though your system may allow it.

Run outside of the project which you want to test:

1. `composer create-project bartlett/php-compatinfo` - this command will install PHP CompatInfo
   and all its dependencies including development dependencies and then build a PHAR file.
   If you have problems with installation of development dependencies you may omit them
   `composer create-project --no-dev --no-scripts bartlett/php-compatinfo`,
   in this case the PHAR file also will not be built, but it is not required anyway.
2. `cd php-compatinfo`
   `composer run post-install-cmd` - this command will build the SQLite database which PHP CompatInfo requires. This operation should not be executed in a production environment! If you want to run PHP CompatInfo in a production environment, then you should check its documentation.
3. `./bin/phpcompatinfo analyser:run --progress ../path/to/project` - this command will analyse the code
   and may produce a huge report, but there should be something like this at the beginning:

   ```
   Extensions Analysis

       Extension REF      EXT min/Max PHP min/Max
       Core      Core     5.1.0       5.1.0
       json      json     5.2.0       5.2.0
    C  mongo     mongo    0.9.0       5.0.0
       pcre      pcre     4.0.0       4.0.0
       session   session  4.0.0       4.0.0
       standard  standard 5.2.3       5.2.3
       Total [6]                      5.2.3
   ```

For details see the aforementioned documentation and built-in help:

- Help message

  ```sh
  ./php-compatinfo/bin/phpcompatinfo --help
  ```
- List available commands

  ```sh
  ./php-compatinfo/bin/phpcompatinfo list
  ```
- Help message about command

  ```sh
  ./php-compatinfo/bin/phpcompatinfo analyser:run --help
  ```

#### Troubleshooting

PHP CompatInfo is unable to parse invalid PHP code, so if you got a `Fatal error` during analysis
then that may be the reason.
Some packages may include testing files with incorrect PHP code which are never executed but used for testing,
example of such a package is `squizlabs/php_codesniffer`.
I suggest to temporarily remove the entire package or only its tests to avoid errors during analysis.

#### Interpretation of results

PHP CompatInfo may produce false-positive and false-negative results.

Example of false-negative: the library can detect that your project uses `PDO`, but unable to detect whether it is used
with `pdo_mysql` or `pdo_pgsql` driver or something else. Although I bet you know which database you are using.

Example of false-positive: some PHP frameworks and libraries may contain classes to work with numerous services
intended to the same purpose.
For example Yii 2 framework has classes to work with `APC`, `APCu`, `memcache`, `memcached` and `XCache`.
PHP CompatInfo will list all these extensions but this does not mean that they are really used in the project,
you have to figure out yourself.
The same situation is possible for image processing PHP extensions `GD`, `Gmagick` and `Imagick` and other extensions.